# Joomla and WCAG 2.0

Tags: joomla, accessibility, wcag

I need to implement some WCAG 2.0 guidelines into a Joomla webpage. I've read a lot about this guidelines on W3C, but the problem is that I really don't know where to start. Please help!

Comment: Pretty much impossible to answer that without knowing what wcag guidelines you're having problems with.

Comment: Where to begin? With the design of your future site maybe? Contrast ratio between colors of text and backgrounds, always visible skip links at the beginning, visible labels on form, explicit links,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest starting by looking at Drupal's example - http://drupal.org/about/accessibility

Probably most interesting would be the issue queue:
http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/drupal?issue_tags=accessibility

It's a big challenge.  Best to work with others in the Joomla community as there are no quick fixes.

Answer (score -1):

Do not get lost in the Ambiguous 780 pages from W3C WCAG, i can not shake the feeling that if one needs that many pages to implement something in HTML, your doing it wrong (do you know a 780page doc for HTML?), a good title therefor IMO would be; "how-to make web-accessibility not accessible, by W3C".

I would recommend the following article:
https://patstapestry.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/tips-and-tricks-for-website-accessibility-testing-with-the-screen-reader-jaws/

following her guidelines you can try tackle the specific problems your pages may have, one-by-one

Also test with NVDA, TalkBack and VoiceOver;
http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/